# Selenium is returning empty text for elements that definitely have text

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm practicing trying to scrape my university's course catalog. I have a few lines in Python that open the url in Chrome and clicks the search button to bring up the course catalog. When I go to extract the texting using `find_elements_by_xpath()`, it returns blank. When I use the dev tools on Chrome, there definitely is text there.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://courses.osu.edu/psp/csosuct/EMPLOYEE/PUB/c/COMMUNITY_ACCESS.OSR_CAT_SRCH.GBL?'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('ptifrmtgtframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="OSR_CAT_SRCH_WK_BUTTON1"]')
element.click()
course = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="OSR_CAT_SRCH_OSR_CRSE_HEADER$0"]')
print(course)
```

I'm trying to extract the text from the element 'OSU_CAT_SRCH_OSR_CRSE_HEADER'. I don't understand why it's not returning the text values especially when I can see that it contains text with dev tools.

Comment: You're not waiting.  One of the pains of Selenium is that it works in real-time.  If the site takes 1/2 second to update the page, then you need to wait for that.  There is a way to say "wait until this element is present", but I don't recall the API name.

Comment: Did you try more time ou another delay? It looks the content isn't ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `text` that is the reason you are not getting the text.

```
course = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="OSR_CAT_SRCH_OSR_CRSE_HEADER$0"]').text
```

Try above changes in last second line

Below is the full code after the changes

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://courses.osu.edu/psp/csosuct/EMPLOYEE/PUB/c/COMMUNITY_ACCESS.OSR_CAT_SRCH.GBL?'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('ptifrmtgtframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="OSR_CAT_SRCH_WK_BUTTON1"]')
element.click()
# wait 10 seconds
course = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="OSR_CAT_SRCH_OSR_CRSE_HEADER$0"]'))
).text
print(course)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to add in an additional 'time.sleep()' to allow the site to run, but adding .text allowed me to extract the text

Comment: I've updated the code, rather than using time.sleep. It would be better to use the Driver Wait

Comment: If your problem is solved, accept the answer